# Plantuml: make a horizontal line to join boxes

Tags: plantuml

I'm trying to make a family tree with PlantUML, so I decided to use `@startmindmap` instead of `@startuml` or another type of diagram. However, I would like tot draw an horizontal line to create marriages. With the following code:

```
@startmindmap
* Mother
* Father
** Son
** Daughter
@endmindmap
```

I get this image:

[image]

What I would like is a line from "Mother" to "Father", so  the childs come from them. Something like this example:

[image]

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is not possible with mindmap type.

Comment: What type should I use?

Comment: Component diagram perhaps

Comment: Also read this thread about feature: https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/discussions/1169

Comment: This template is awesome, @StevenSpungin! Thanks a lot. This works for me!